# Cambiar de color el titulo de la AppBar

Tags: android

por favor necesito ayuda no puedo cambiar el color del titulo de la appBar, en el mio me sale negro y quisiera cambiarlo  blanco..en este caso estoy usando una toolbar lo intente con todo
le puse `<item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>` el acento a mi thema pero no lo cambia ..tambien lo hize por codigo 
        `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));` tampoco me lo cambia y tambien lo hize por xml pero ninguno funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Complementa la pregunta con más código, para hallar el posible problema

Comment: agrega la transparencia  (primeros 2 caracteres)  toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF")); ve mi respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usa [**`setTitleTextColor()`**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setTitleTextColor(int)),

Definiendo el hex del color,  por ejemplo

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

#### Aquí es importante agregar el Alpha (transparencia), ya que si no se tiene, puede tener problemas al cambiar el color de uno previamente definido.

Se puede cargar un color definido en el SDK:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

También puedes cargar un código hex en string y parsearlo para convertirlo a Color:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys bueno no me lo cambio pero si encontré la solución como puse un toolbar solo añadi este codigo al xml del appBar que lo envuelve android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"